# How to factor exponential terms in Sympy Python?

Tags: python, spyder, sympy

How do I transform an expression like this:

y = [x*e^(x/2) + e^x + e^(x/2)]^2

in this:

y = {e^(x/2)*[x + e^(x/2) + 1]}^2

using Sympy??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the factoring doesn't recognize the exponential as well as a power. So convert the `exp(x/2) -> y`, factor, then back substitute:

```
>>> eq
(x*exp(x/2) + exp(x/2) + exp(x))**2
>>> factor(eq.subs(exp(x/2),y)).subs(y,exp(x/2))
(x + exp(x/2) + 1)**2*exp(x)
```